# MySQL: How to select rows which has next lager ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table as such:

```
ID   Content

3      blah

5      blah    <--

6      blah

7      blah
```

I want to get the row with id number next higher than 4 (which would be 5)

I tired

```
SELECT MIN (DISTINCT id) 
FROM mytablename
WHERE id > 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytablename
WHERE id > 4
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

#### Demo Here